# How to extract value by key from json response in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm using getResponse api for getting updated about subscribers.
This is what is printing after `var_dump($result);`

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["updated"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

How do i extract / decode / encode the result to request the key: "update" and get it's value: 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: `echo $result->updated;` Its a standard php object

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```php
// json object.
$contents = '{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}';
    
// Option 1: through the use of an array.
$jsonArray = json_decode($contents,true);
    
$key = "firstName";
    
$firstName = $jsonArray[$key];
        
// Option 2: through the use of an object.
$jsonObj = json_decode($contents);
    
$firstName = $jsonObj->$key;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's already decoded, as you can see [on the man pages](http://php.net/json_decode), the default behavior of `json_decode` is to decode a JSON string to an instance of `stdClass`, if you want an assoc array, simply write:

```
$string = '{"updated":1}';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
echo $array['updated'];
```

But you can just access the `updated` value on the object, because it's just a public property anyway:

```
$obj = json_decode($string);
echo $obj->updated;
```